# Sync Gateway Admin REST API: Sync Gateway Architect vs Full Admin

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I’m facing an issue with Couchbase Server 7.2 and Sync Gateway 3.1, both of which I’m using in their Community Editions. I’m having trouble accessing the Sync Gateway Admin REST API; all my attempts result in permission errors.

After reading the documentation, my understanding is that the Admin REST API might not be fully accessible in the Community Edition. It seems that the roles required to access this API are restricted to the Enterprise Edition. [See Link](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/rest-api-access.html).

In the Community Edition, we only have the full admin role, which apparently doesn’t grant access to most of the Admin REST API endpoints.

Is my understanding correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated.